# I can't get my CSS File to Load in my Razor Pages (ASP.Net Core)

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following syntax in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/lib/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

I can see the ~/content/site.css in the Page Source but the styles isn't being applied. The site.css only has one entry as follows:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background: #48b9e5;
}
```

If I manually add the style to my Razor Page via the  tag it works just fine.  What am I missing?

--- Val

Comment: What's the link tag look like rendered into the html when viewed in the browser?  Does it include the tilde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo:

Tasks.cshtml(You need to put css between `<style></style>`):

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my _Layout.cshtml:
[image]
Here is html of Tasks.cshtml:
[image]
Here is Network of Tasks.cshtml:
[image]
result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Yiyi, thanks for responding.  I think you misunderstood my question.  I have it working with the <style> tags, however I want to have this as part of my _Layout.cshtml so that I don't have to include this in every module.

Comment: I have updated my answer to put css into _Layout.cshtml,You can add `<style></style>` into `<head></head>`.

Comment: Got it. Not sure why I just can't add a .CSS file like the other ones, but as long as it works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that css file can't override styles used in bootstrap or other liberary
try this `background: #48b9e5 !important;`

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for responding.  Unfortunately that did not do the trick.

Comment: Got it. so, if I want to override Bootstrap-specific styles, I have to include them in the _Layout file instead of linking in a .CSS file.  Seems counter-intuitive, but if it works!